# I can't find a way to practically define an array, push some values and output them as a string in VBA? (new array, push, join)

Tags: arrays, vba, join

I've found out how to create an array, but I cannot push items easily. I must maintain a index to the next position and increment every time I push an item;

I've also found the collection which has the nice .Add method that acts exactly like a push method. But how I join them? The global Join method doesn't work with Collections.

What I'm missing here? anybody could help me to define an array, push items easily without an index and then output them to a string spaced by ", "?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do that directly. Arrays in VBA usually need to be indexed and dimensioned before use.

You can use a dynamic array and resize before assigning a variable:

```
Dim arr() As String
ReDim arr(0)

arr(UBound(arr)) = "Some String"
ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
arr(UBound(arr)) = "Some Other String"
ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
arr(UBound(arr)) = "Some 3rd String"

MsgBox Join(arr, ",")
```

The preserve key word maintains the values in the array rather than overwriting them. The above approach is generally not recommended however since Preserve is costly and only allows you to resize the last dimension of an array.

Collections are different, are slower and generally less flexible in a VBA environment (you haven't said which environment, but I'll assume Excel)

```
Dim coll As Collection
Dim itm As Variant
Dim tempS As String


Set coll = New Collection
coll.Add "Some String"
coll.Add "Some Other String"
coll.Add "Some 3rd String"

For Each itm In coll
    tempS = tempS & itm & ","
Next itm

MsgBox Left(tempS, Len(tempS) - 1)
```

You need to loop through them to build an array.

There are a numerous of other options depending on your needs

**Built in method**

for strings, have a look at split:

```
Const stri As String = "Some String, Some Other String, Some 3rd String"
Dim arr() As String

arr = Split(stri, ",")

MsgBox Join(arr, ",")
```

**Using External objects**

Scripting Dictionary

```
Dim dic As Object

Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")
dic.Add "1", "Some String"
dic.Add "2", "Some Other String"
dic.Add "3", "Some 3rd String"

Debug.Print Join(dic.items, ",")
```

.Net arrayList

```
Dim al As Object

Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")
al.Add "Some String"
al.Add "Some Other String"
al.Add "Some 3rd String"

MsgBox Join(al.ToArray(), ",")
```

Comment: thanks that worked. I've used the collection and then made a Join function that will join the collection's items... It's hard to choose one answer to the other but this contains information for both things array and collection, therefore I think is more useful for other people searching for this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Collection object, and then loop through it with a For...Each statement:

```
Dim colItems As New Collection
Dim strOutput As String

'Add Items to Collection
colItems.Add "Item 1"
colItems.Add "Item 2"
colItems.Add "Item 3"

'Loop through the collection and place items in strOutput
For Each Item in colItems
    If strOutput <> "" Then strOutput = strOutput & ","
    strOutput = strOutput & Item
Next

Msgbox strOutput
```

The messagebox will read `Item 1,Item 2,Item3`.

This line of code:

```
If strOutput <> "" Then strOutput = strOutput & ","
```

is to add a comma after every item, except for the first time through the loop (before any items have been added).

Comment: thanks that worked. I've used the collection and then made a Join function that will join the collection's items... I've also didn't knew the "trick" in the for each in order to have commas only between the items ;)